# google reCaptcha in browser extension

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recaptcha, browser-extension

I'm trying to add google reCaptcha to my V3 browser extension (react) but seems like it's impossible to use external scripts like this in my index.html `<head>` tag

```
<script defer src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/enterprise.js?render=**RECAPTCHA_KEY**"></script>
```

There is an info here https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-overview/#remotely-hosted-code

```
A key security improvement in Manifest V3 is that extensions can't load remote code like JavaScript or Wasm files. 
This lets us more reliably and efficiently review the safe behavior of extensions when they're submitted to the Chrome Web Store. 
Specifically, all logic must be included in the extension's package.

Instead of remote code, we recommend the use of remote configuration files. 
See the migration guide for more about how to work with this change.
```

Any tips on how to to make it work?

Thank you in advance!